# Kohana blank page, no errors

Tags: xampp, kohana, kohana-2

So, I've got this working on windows, and now I'm trying to get it to work on ubuntu.

I have a Kohana 2.3 app I am developing, at localhost/myapp.  When I navigate to that URL, I just get a blank screen.  I can echo 'hello' in index.php and that works.  The problem seems to be with Kohana::setup() in bootstrap.php - echoing a string before that line prints it out, after that line it does nothing.

The Kohana core directories are located in a different place to the app, at /opt/lampp/htdocs/kohana.  In my index.php file:

```
$kohana_modules = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/kohana/modules';

$kohana_system = '/opt/lampp/htdocs/kohana/system';
```

This doesn't seem to be the problem, as if I change those values to something else I get a proper PHP error.  Error reporting is definitely enabled.

Any clues how I can work out what is wrong?  The same setup (as far as I can tell) is working properly on Windows on the same machine.

Thanks.  I'm using XAMPP on Ubuntu 12.10, Kohana 2.3, PHP 5.4

Comment: Try to look in the server (apache) logs .. what is there?

Comment: Thanks - there's nothing in the Apache or PHP error logs, if that's where you mean?

Comment: Well, maybe kohana system is not loading though there should be something in the logs. Nothing not even on application/logs ?

Comment: Nope, nothing there.  It might be worth mentioning I am fairly new to linux and Kohana.

Comment: Ahh .. ok then. An idea is this .. download the Kohana 2.3 branch and clean install it. Does it start (are all requirements *green*?) ? If yes .. then change the system/modules folder to be the ones from /opt....

Comment: 2.3 doesn't work on PHP 5.4, install 5.3, set display_errors to On, and disable E_STRICT

Comment: 2.3 works in PHP 5.4 if you apply this small patch to it : https://gist.github.com/2881489

Comment: Confirming that the patch provided by @SorinTrimbitas now gives me output in Kohana 2.3 whereas before I had blank pages like the asker.

Comment: Yep, the patch works for me too.

Comment: Are your filenames all in lowercase? I think on linux machines you need them to be as they are used

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

1. Edit system/core/Kohana.php
2. Modify the close_buffers function (around line 626)
3. Comment out "ob_end_clean();" at the end of the function